# Sigma algebra generated by set $C$ is the sigma field generated by pre-images of all real borel sets under the indicator functions of sets in $C$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $C $ be a collection of subsets of a set $X$ , let $F$ denote the collection of indicator functions of $C$ , let $\sigma (F):=\sigma (\{f^{-1}(B): B$ is a borel subset of $\mathbb R , f \in F \})$ , let $\sigma (C)$ be the usual sigma algebra on $X$ generated by $C$ . Then is it true that $\sigma (F)=\sigma (C)$ ?

Comment: Generally not. What are the possible values of $\mathbb{1}_A^{-1}(B)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer : it is either empty , or whole $X$ , or a set in $C$ or complement of a set in $C$ depending on $B$ contains neither $0$ nor $1$ , contains both $0,1$ , contains $1$ but not $0$ , contains $0$ but not $1$ respectively

Comment: You answered for the family $F$, while I asked for a specific indicator function. No big deal. So we see that $$\sigma(F) = \{ \varnothing, X\} \cup C \cup \{ X\setminus A : A \in C\}.$$ Can you find examples where that is not a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @DanielFischer : Sorry for the confusion , I edited , I indeed meant that to be sigma field generated by such collection

Comment: With the description of $\{ f^{-1}(B) : \dotsc\}$ from above, you should be able to find the answer to your question.